# How to shorten a string by replacing some characters with an ellipsis

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using an `<input type="file">` element for file upload, and getting the filename. I am now trying to display the file name, but reduce the total string length. To achieve that, I wanted to add an ellipsis at a specific index and display the rest of the characters.

Like for example: if the filename is **abcxyz.exe**, I want the filename to look like **abc..z.exe**.

Is there any way to display it in this way ?

I am using this method, but it adds an ellipsis to replace all characters from the position given as a parameter.

```
function truncate(str, n){
    return (str.length > n) ? str.substr(0, n-5) + '&hellip;' + str.substring(str.indexOf(".") + 1) : str;
};
```

Comment: *"but it adds elipsis to the whole character from the position given as a paramter"* - I don't understand this part of your question. If you've written this code, and it does not do what you want, write it differently? If you have *not* written this code, give credit to the person who did and include a link to the source. And *then* analyze the code and write it differently. I don't really understand what the question is here, apart from "rewrite this for me".

Comment: @Tomalak In JavaScript, i know to get the character from a specific index position which returns the whole text specified from a given index position. Here my question is to not add the elipsis to the entire text from a specified index position. I just wanted to get a part of the text and add characters. Hope you understood my question.

Comment: *"I just wanted to get a part of the text and add characters."* - I still don't get it. The code you show uses `str.substr()` and calculated indexes. You need to do the exact same thing.

Comment: To clarify your issue, please add the code that initialises a specific string to a sample filename, then calls truncate, and then outputs it. Then tell us how that output is different from what you expected. I agree with Tomalak: currently it is not clear what the problem is.

Comment: Okay i will add a snippet in the post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, *n* represents the maximum length of the string. If the string is longer, you want to replace a substring by the ellipsis character, such that the resulting string has a length of *n*. If possible, you also want that ellipsis to be placed before the extension of the filename, leaving one character visible before the final dot.

Some things to consider:

- Use `lastIndexOf` instead of `indexOf`, as the last occurrence really determines where the file extension starts.
- Don't use the `substr` method, as it is considered a legacy feature in ECMAScript. I prefer `slice`.
- Make the necessary calculations so to ensure that after the insertion of the ellipsis you arrive at the correct length.
- Deal with boundary cases, where the filename has no extension, or where the extension itself is longer than *n*.
- Don't use the HTML entity `&hellip;`, as that will limit the use of this function to HTML output only. Instead put the actual `…` character, which will both work for HTML and plain text.

Here is the code I would suggest:

```
function truncate(str, n) {
    if (str.length <= n) return str; // Nothing to do
    if (n <= 1) return "…"; // Well... not much else we can return here!
    let dot = str.lastIndexOf("."); // Where the extension starts
    // How many characters from the end should remain:
    let after = dot < 0 ? 1 : Math.max(1, Math.min(n - 2, str.length - dot + 2));
    // How many characters from the start should remain:
    let before = n - after - 1; // Account for the ellipsis
    return str.slice(0, before) + "…" + str.slice(-after);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My english is bad, i am happy you understood my point of view.